# Playing Cards question

Tags: card-games

Say I have a hand of X playing cards drawn from a standard 52-card deck, where X can be 1 through 10.

Then say I also have a second deck of the 52 standard playing cards, and draw a card from there. (alternately, say I rolled 1d13)

I need to calculate the odds (at least approximately) that at least 1 card in my X-card hand will A: MATCH the number drawn/rolled, or B: BE WITHIN ONE OF that value. (So if I drew/rolled a 6, B would be satisfied if the cards in my hand included a 5, 6, or 7)

Comment: Does ace count as next to both two and king?

Comment: Hint:  In your example, the probability that none of your $X$ cards are among $5,6,7$ is $\binom {40}{X}/\binom {52}{X}$.

Comment: Aces are not intended to be within 1 of the king, or vice versa. I’m treating it as a method of generating a number between 1 and 13.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean ranks $\pmod {13}$, so that Aces are next to both $2's$ and Kings:

Then, for part $A$ we note that there are exactly $4$ cards that match the preferred rank.  Thus the probability that none of your $X$ cards matches the preferred rank is $$\binom {48}X\Big /\binom{52}X$$  It follows that the answer you want is $$1\,-\,\binom {48}X\Big /\binom{52}X$$

Similarly for $B$ the answer is $$1\,-\,\binom {40}X\Big /\binom{52}X$$

If you don't want Aces to be next to both $2's$ and Kings then $A$ stays the same, but you have to modify $B$ to account for the possibility that the preferred rank only has one neighbor.

Comment: I appear to have a gap in my fundamental knowledge- what is that (48 X) notation? (i.e. just the term for it, I can look up rest from there)

Comment: That's a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  Sometimes written $^{48}C_X$.

Answer (score 0):

When $X=1$ it is easy (assuming the ranks are circular so ace is next to both two and king).  You have $1/13$ chance of a match and $3/13$ chance of being within one.

When $X=2$ part A should be easy at $2/13$ except that the two cards you drew might match.  The chance of a match is $\frac 3{51}$ because after you draw the first card there are $3$ of the remaining $51$ that match.  The chance the die matches one of the two cards is then $\frac {48}{51}\cdot \frac 2{13}+\frac 3{51}\cdot \frac 1{13}=\frac {99}{663}=\frac {33}{221}\approx 0.1493$  Part B has more trouble with overlap.  If the two cards match the chance is $3/13$, if they are one apart $4/13$, if they are two apart $5/13$ and if the are further $6/13$.  Getting the exact value is a fair mess, and for $X$ larger it is messier yet.

Comment: Unless I am misreading, always possible, you can ignore duplicates and such.  For part $A$ the probability that no cards match the favored rank is $\binom {48}X/\binom {52}X$, no?  So the probability that at least one matches can be found by subtraction.

Comment: @lulu:  I took the 1d13 to mean that we are only interested in matches in rank.  The fact that part B is about being one away supports this.  Then it is possible to draw matching cards in the first part.

Comment: Yes...that's how I am reading it as well.  There are $4$ cards of the preferred rank, hence $48$ non-matches.  Anyway, I posted my version below.  Let me know if it is wrong.

Comment: @lulu:   I see what you mean.  I was thinking of matches between the cards drawn from the first deck.  Your approach is much simpler.